# 24 hours in time intervals of 30 minutes

Tags: intervals, webi

I have searched through previous posts but cannot find the answer I am looking for. I would like to get 30 minutes intervals for 24 hours e.g.

Starts = 00:30, 01:00, 01:30, 02:00 etc
Ends - 24:00

If you could please point me in the right direction. Can this be done using custom query script within web intelligence query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do this natively in WebI, but you can certainly brute force this in a free-hand SQL query. The database I am using is SQL Server. Your SQL syntax might be different depending on your database platform.

The easiest approach would be a bunch of unions...

```
SELECT '00:30' AS TimeInterval
UNION SELECT '01:00'
UNION SELECT '01:30'
UNION SELECT '02:00'
UNION SELECT '02:30'
UNION SELECT '03:00'
UNION SELECT '03:30'
UNION SELECT '04:00'
UNION SELECT '04:30'
UNION SELECT '05:00'
UNION SELECT '05:30'
UNION SELECT '06:00'
UNION SELECT '06:30'
UNION SELECT '07:00'
UNION SELECT '07:30'
UNION SELECT '08:00'
UNION SELECT '08:30'
UNION SELECT '09:00'
UNION SELECT '09:30'
UNION SELECT '10:00'
UNION SELECT '10:30'
UNION SELECT '11:00'
UNION SELECT '11:30'
UNION SELECT '12:00'
UNION SELECT '12:30'
UNION SELECT '13:00'
UNION SELECT '13:30'
UNION SELECT '14:00'
UNION SELECT '14:30'
UNION SELECT '15:00'
UNION SELECT '15:30'
UNION SELECT '16:00'
UNION SELECT '16:30'
UNION SELECT '17:00'
UNION SELECT '17:30'
UNION SELECT '18:00'
UNION SELECT '18:30'
UNION SELECT '19:00'
UNION SELECT '19:30'
UNION SELECT '20:00'
UNION SELECT '20:30'
UNION SELECT '21:00'
UNION SELECT '21:30'
UNION SELECT '22:00'
UNION SELECT '22:30'
UNION SELECT '23:00'
UNION SELECT '23:30'
UNION SELECT '24:00'
```

Here is a little more elegant approach using a CTE...

```
DECLARE @startnum INT = 1;
DECLARE @endnum INT = 48;
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1 FROM cte WHERE num + 1 <= @endnum
)
SELECT CASE
           WHEN num < 48 THEN
                -- Here is the logical progression working from the inside out
                -- 1. convert GETDATE() to a DATE to get rid of the time
                -- 2. convert the result of #1 back to a DATETIME
                -- 3. add the appropriate number of minutes
                -- 4. convert to VARCHAR(5) style of 8 to get hh:mi
               CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DATEADD(MINUTE, num * 30, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))), 8)
           ELSE
               '24:00'
       END AS TimeInterval
FROM   cte;
```

Hopefully, you can make one of those work for you.